# Refactor > Move overlaps the location of another project

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to move an Android project to a difference directory in the workspace, using Refactor > Move.

The problem is that the "Move Project" dialog box keeps the OK button disabled, while issuing the following message in red:

> \winshare\sandbox\workspace\NewDirName
>   overlaps the location of another
>   project: NewDirName

The funny thing is... a directory named NewDirName doesn't even exist!

(I later tried creating such directory outside of Eclipse but that didn't help)

Any idea why this is?

I am using Eclipse 3.6.1 64-bit with the latest Android SDK 9 (under Windows 7).

Comment: Why dont you just import the project from the new workspace?

Comment: @Ravi Vyas I know how to import projects but the purpose of this question is to find out why 'Refactor > Move' doesn't work. Is this a bug in Eclipse or ADT? Is this documented behavior that I somehow missed and failed to understand?

Comment: I _think_ this may be related to Eclipse keeping track of projects in your current workspace. If you look in <your_workspace_path>/.metadata/plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects, you may find reference to NewDirName there.

Comment: Eclipse does this to me, too.  I just create a new project, and copy the files over.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Delete the project. Do *not* delete resources from the filesystem.
2. You can then rename the project folder outside of Eclipse (using command line or file manager GUI)
3. Now import the project back into the workspace (File -> Import -> Existing Project into Workspace.

The error message you're getting is misleading. Refactoring operations are not intended for projects. The problem is that the plugin should remove the Refactor options when the selected item is a project rather than a package or class.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled over the same problem ("overlaps the location of another project" error) trying to create a new project for a set of tutorial files unpacked from a ZIP file. This problem appeared in a couple of forums so I'm cross-posting the answer so it's available in both.

I'm using Vista, Eclipse 3.7.0

I don't know what "File | New | Project | Android Project | Create project from existing source" is supposed to do but I couldn't get it to work for the above unzipped files. I kept getting that error.

I found what did work is:
1) Copy the unzipped file tree for the project to wherever you want it to eventually reside.
2) File | Import | General | Existing Projects into Workspace | Select root directory:
and point it to wherever you put the zipped files, check-box on for the Project that is the one you want, then Finish

Step 2 seems to not actually move the files anywhere (even though the term 'import' implied that to me), but it seems to just make Eclipse aware of where the project is located and it uses the project from that directory.

That seems to work at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case with Eclipse 4.2, I had changed the folder structure from:

```
./workspace/%project_folder%
```

to 
`./2014/android-things/%project_folder%` -> symlink `./workspace/%project_folder%`

The new 2014 folder was actually a git repo.
Workspace show no projects, and reimporting didn't worked - so I had to delete the symlink and renamed the project under `android-things` to fully qualified name `org.domain.%project_folder%` to avoid possible conflicts.

Comment: Offtopic: this development environment really has *the* quirks.